# Distribution $P_X$ and c.d.f $F_X(a)$ of a random variable (defined piecewise)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having a bit of trouble computing $P_X$ and $F_X(a)$ for a random variable defined piecewise. Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ equiped with Borel $\sigma-field$ and Lebesgue measure.

Ok when it comes to a "simple" random variable like, for example $X(\omega)=2\omega$ I don't have any trouble. Take $A=[a,b]$ then,
$$P_X(A) = P(\{X\in[a,b]\})=P(\{\omega\in\Omega:a\le2\omega\le b\})=P([\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2}]) = \frac{b-a}{2}$$ Similarly i compute $F_X(a)$ by computing $P(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\le a\})$.

But i keep getting it wrong for a random variable defined piecewise. For example how would I compute $P_X$ and $F_X(a)$ for:
$$X(\omega) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} \omega, &\omega\ge\frac{1}{2}\\ 0, &otherwise \end{array} \right.$$ Does this look correct for the $F_X(a)$:
$$F_X(a) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} 0, &a<0\\ {\frac{1}{2}}, &0\le a<{\frac{1}{2}}\\ a, &{\frac{1}{2}}\le a<1\\ 1, &a\ge1 \end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P_{X}\left(A\right)=P\left(\left\{ \omega\mid X\left(\omega\right)\in A\right\} \right)=P\left(\left\{ \omega\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\mid\omega\in A\right\} \right)+P\left(\left\{ \omega\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\mid0\in A\right\} \right)$$
This with: $$\left\{ \omega\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\mid\omega\in A\right\} =A\cap\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$$
and:

$\left\{ \omega\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\mid0\in A\right\} =\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$
if $0\in A$ and $\left\{ \omega\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\mid0\in A\right\} =\varnothing$
otherwise.

---

Explanation: if $B:=\left\{ \omega\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\mid0\in A\right\}$ then $$\omega\in B\iff0\leq\omega<\frac{1}{2}\wedge0\in A$$ and the statement
on the right side can only be true if $0\in A$.

---

$F_{X}\left(a\right)=P_{X}\left(\left(-\infty,a\right]\right)$ and
can be treated as shown.

Comment: ok Thank you. I "think" I understand. I updated my post with the c.d.f of X. If I understood right, then it should be correct.

Comment: On base of your update I confirm that you understand.

Comment: How could I write Px in a "nicer" way? Maybe using the indicator function or dirac measure